# Why do we use term "arm" to express different treatment "group" in clinical trials?

Tags: terminology, clinical-trials

I'm reading papers about randomization in clinical trials. I'm curious why we use the term "arm" such as in "two-arm trials" to express "treatment and control groups".

I Googled this question, but I didn't find related answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll bet it's from the shape of a typical flow diagram used to describe RCTs, where one starts with a box showing the total number of patients, branching to (usually two) boxes housing the frequency of each treatment group.  See [consort diagrams](https://trialsjournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1745-6215-12-253).

Comment: Wow, make sense! Thank you!

Comment: This would be consistent with the translation of "arm" in French and Spanish in the context of clinical trials - "bras" and "brazo", respectively. Both words originally describe the human upper limb, and by extension things ressembling it (like the main branches of a tree). Contrary to the English word "arm", they are not homonyms of the word "weapon", so at least we can exclude any etymology related to that.

Answer (score 3):

An "arm" is a well-defined term that potentially captures more information than just treatment assignment. In some more complex trial designs, you might have multiple indications recruited and randomized separately, you can have subjects who form a safety run in - that is they receive the active treatment with 100% probability and aren't part of any ITT analysis - or you can have cross-over schedules that depend on the subject disposition - with rerandomization or optional open label extension. There is also a notion of a single arm trial - whereas it would be nonsense to say each subject was "randomized to the active treatment group".

It makes sense that authors might use "arm" interchangeably with "treatment assignment" for the analysis of simple, parallel randomized trials. But here's no loss of generality.

Agree with Frank the etymology more than likely has to do with visualizing the flowchart, and other graphical terms like branch or edge could have been equally valid had they been adopted in lieu of "arm".

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks a lot!